# How to turn off 'make some noise' to continue in arcade games in Rocksmith 2014

Tags: rocksmith-2014

When I'm playing the arcade minigames in Rocksmith 2014 (particularly Scale Warriors and Castle Chordead), I'm usually willing to just end my gameplay when I die, especially when I have a decent score at that time. Unfortunately, the 'MAKE SOME NOISE to continue' popup comes up exceptionally quickly, usually before I have a chance to mute my strings, so I end up in this terrible loop of restarting a section and losing points for restarting, and getting very frustrated.

Is there a way to turn the "'Make Some Noise' to continue" option off in arcade mode?

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning the volume down on your guitar. Mine doesn't do that.